Dynamically named variables from query
I want to write a SQL Server stored procedure that contains the following:
Imagine a query like this:
SELECT VARNAME, TYPE, VARVALUE, LEN(CAST(VARVALUE AS VARCHAR(5))) + 1 AS LENGTH
FROM SOMETABLE;

And further imagine it returns something like the following:



VARNAME
TYPE
VARVALUE
LENGTH




RED
INT
42
3


GREEN
VARCHAR
GRASS
6


PURPLE
CHAR
5
2



Using this data, I want to end up with a set of declared variables that are the equivalent of this:
DECLARE 
    @RED INT = 42,
    @GREEN VARCHAR(6) = 28,
    @PURPLE CHAR(2) = 5 `

so that I can do something like this later on in the stored procedure:
PRINT @RED
PRINT @GREEN
PRINT @PURPLE

MYVAR = @PURPLE + ' LBS OF ' + @GREEN + ' YIELDS ' + @RED + ' SQ INCHES OF PLANTS'

I've tried a bunch of things, like executing dynamic SQL, like writing query output that takes the form of DECLARE statements that I would execute, but none of it worked, because even if the variables did get created (I have no idea if they really did or not), I couldn't use them later on in the code because they aren't declared when I compile the stored procedure, and that makes the compile fail.
I am caught in a classic Catch-22 and I have no more ideas about how to accomplish this.
Is it possible? Can you show me how?
You might be interested in why I want this, and you might want to tell me how it's a bad idea. My purpose is too long to describe, and trust me, this will be a great idea if it works, so I'd like to steer away from those discussions please.  I've pretty much convinced myself that it is impossible, but I thought I'd ask before I completely give up.
Thanks in advance.

You can absolutely do that, but everything has to be dynamic SQL so that they exist when the query runs

Please show what you tried, so we might help with it.

The trick is remembering that not only must your DECLARE statements be in the dynamic SQL, but so must the other T-SQL code that utilizes them.

This sounds like a XY problem. What are you trying to achieve actually

@Squirrel didn't you read OP's command not to ask why

Yes I did. But I can't help it :)

I severely doubt the "this will be a great idea if it works" - I can think of no circumstance in which this will be the best solution to a problem

My comment would be that if you can't figure out the syntax to write this, it will not be a great idea even if it works. But yeah, think what the string you execute should look if it weren't dynamic sql and then just build it step by step

Very funny siggy!  Anyway, you're not the only one to point it out, but I thought of the idea while reading your comment, so I'll respond here.  The advice: the downstream statements, like PRINT, need to be dynamic too.  BINGO!  What might work well is to put those in the table as well and generate them the same way, at the same time.  That not only works, but it helps keep me organized and I can reference everything in one place.  I can even add a column or two to give them names and other characteristics so I can filter the ones I want, in the order I want, for when I want.

<bad_idea> If everything is a sql_variant then ... . </bad_idea>

Sounds like you'll just be reimplementing the sql server language but using a table structure to describe statements rather than sql code. Sure, it's been done before (graphql, 4gl etc), but this all sounds like something called "Inner-Plattform Effect", where you're reimplementing the database inside the database. You might want to avoid people knowing sql, the fallacy here is that you still need to know it to write those variables declarations etc, so you don't really gain anything. Eventually, you will write a wrapper around the tables to create another inner plattform "level" :)

Here you go:
DECLARE @RED INT = (select cast(varvalue as int) from sometable where varname = 'RED');

etc.  I suppose you could generate that code dynamically. If you generate this in a dynamic batch, you'll have to include all the downstream code that references the variable in the dynamic batch.

I like this a lot, and I appreciate the advice about the downstream code, which I responded to up above.  I'll give this a try and report back, hopefully with some code.  Thanks.
